# Is possible to have access to the email of the users that liked my page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I get the email with the list of all the users that likes my fan page on Facebook?

I'm using Facebook graph using the url:
[https://graph.facebook.com/['fan page id']?fields=likes&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBACnbIeL5pDFKPQtjAqebZA4aRJKwX1mgFM3502cSxpSw2ssN4gG5r4arZBA2tIsASD698qB9CHaOZBTYd3Ppkj21iMypzBPITVcjLHZB](https://graph.facebook.com/%5B%27fan%20page%20id%27%5D?fields=likes&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBACnbIeL5pDFKPQtjAqebZA4aRJKwX1mgFM3502cSxpSw2ssN4gG5r4arZBA2tIsASD698qB9CHaOZBTYd3Ppkj21iMypzBPITVcjLHZB)

But it's only returning the number of likes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet available.

The possible actions with facebook api for a facebook page are present [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

But it is possible to check if an user has liked your page.
Here's a [Stack Overflow Question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/check-if-user-liked-page) that helps you.